# Millionth Stack Overflow question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Do Atwood's Angels plan to do something to celebrate one million questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: This is... a half-dupe. It's a dupe of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58128/can-we-have-a-party-when-we-hit-1-million-questions-closed), which was closed as a dupe of a third question, but the third question has been deleted.

Comment: @Pop, we should leave at least one of these open...right?

Comment: @jjn, not sure why you're asking me.... I thought this was a full-on dupe, did the search and posted my results. FWIW -- as you know but others might not be able to see -- nobody's voted to close so far.

Comment: @Pop, I guess I figured that by pointing out the dupe, you were in favor of closing.

Comment: Jayjayguy, you are bad at editing questions.

Comment: Another kinda-related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54249/contest-to-predict-date-and-time-that-stackoverflow-will-eclipse-1-000-000-questi

Comment: @Toronto, I try to change as little of the original as possible.  So, I wouldn't say I'm back, our styles just differ.

Comment: I suggest deleting 90% of the questions, answers, and comments (uh, make that *all* comments). After all, 90% of everything is crap, and SO is not exempt from Sturgeon's law ;)

Comment: Jayayy: I would say you're bad. Our styles differ insofar that yours is bad and mine is good.

Comment: @Toronto, I guess I can't argue with logic.

Comment: Now, let's not get off-topic. Can someone finally post the answers "Yes", "No", and "Perhaps", so we can just start voting?

Comment: yugnjj: You're darned right you can't.

Comment: Done. You're welcome.

Comment: @Reg, why didn't you?

Comment: And now I can't vote. See? I am so much more selfless than all you jerks.

Comment: @Popular Demand: I had no idea how to post such short answers.

Comment: @Reg, `"Yes <!--Some html comment to push the char count over X-->"`

Comment: @jin: yeah, I have seen Jon B's source code by now. In fact, I was aware of quite a few approaches that had worked at some point in history, but I also knew that at least some of them were no longer tolerated, and I couldn't be bothered researching.

Comment: @Reg, There is still one trick that works in comments too!  But it will cost you for me to share that.

Comment: @mmy, well, you have super mod powers, so thats cheating.

Comment: I actually thought the zero-width space trick wouldn't work unless they were surrounded by non-whitespace characters (which is apparently what Toronto thought also). Yours is a lot easier to do, though.

Comment: I'm too lazy to figure out how jjugs is doing it.

Comment: @mmy, wait, you can see my source???  Noooooo!! My secret is out.

Comment: Huh. It doesn't work with U200B, but it does work with regular whitespace characters. That's odd. I'm going to have to have a talk with Atwood about this.

Comment: Does this make me one of the cool kids?

Comment: @Jon, good effort though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps

Answer (score 6):

[Yes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/e836a5e0-770a-4a99-93a1-751417b7bab4/view-source)

Comment: +1, simple, most likely truthful, but cruel.

Answer (score 3):

Not A Good Example

Comment: you misspelled "meh."

Comment: Wrong window. :)

Answer (score 3):

If, as I suspect, the question count doesn't reflect deleted questions, they've probably already missed it.  Unless, of course, you don't want to count deleted questions. Then there could be multiple ones that end up being the one millionth question depending on how many (earlier) questions get deleted after the boundary is passed.

Answer (score 2):

No

Answer (score 2):

```
Atwood’s Angels
will <blink>not</blink>
celebrate the
one millionth question.
```

Comment: Atwood's Angels will not blink?

Comment: @mmyers: Thank heavens. I've had it up to *here* with blinking angels!

Comment: Obligatory Doctor Who: *Don't blink. Blink and you're dead. Don't turn your back. Don't look away. And don't blink. Good Luck.*

Comment: @mmyers, Dr. Who?

Comment: @jjnguy: Naturally.

Comment: @mmy - glad to know I'm not the only one on here who enjoys awesome.

Comment: @Jon B: I actually prefer Star Trek to Doctor Who; I haven't even seen *Blink!*, though I've heard about it enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It's all part of our master plan.

If we hit that bullseye, the rest of the dominoes will fall like a house of cards. Checkmate.

Comment: It's like getting a hole in one ringer in the tenth frame.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the unique position of being able to provide a single, most definite answer that is consistent with every other answer so far:

There is a plan but it won't get implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff is not an "angel" he is a "vampire". You have sorely mistaken the two terms.

Proof: His avatar.

Comment: Irrelevant. Charlie wasn't one of Charlie's Angels himself, after all.

Comment: @Popular: Yes, but vampires never associate w/ angels. It's just impossible. Vampires only associate w/ other vampires.

Comment: @thyrgle, citation needed.

Comment: I always thought of him as more of a zombie based on his avatar ...

Comment: @C. Ross: Zombies are green. Vampires are black.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be it: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/25864280740

But, I don't know if that would be to celebrate it, or as a punishment to us all :-S :-S